# Display message when some or all checkboxes aren't checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this page that has multiple checkboxes and when clicked, an element appears.

I have this stripped down version to show it simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" id="check1"  onclick="box1()"><br>
Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" id="check2"  onclick="box2()">

<p id="fill">No boxes are checked</p>

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox1 is CHECKED!</p>
<p id="text2" style="display:none">Checkbox2 is CHECKED!</p>


<script>
function box1() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("check1");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var fill = document.getElementById("fill");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
      text.style.display = "block";
      fill.style.display = "none";
  } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
      fill.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
<script>
function box2() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("check2");
  var text = document.getElementById("text2");
  var fill = document.getElementById("fill");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
    fill.style.display = "none";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
     fill.style.display = "block";
  }
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the text shows even a box is checked as shown in the image. How can I do this effectively? thanks!

[image]

Comment: You obviously need to check the status of _all_ checkboxes at the same time, and not just the current one the click happened on. I would do this in a loop, and switch a flag if you encounter an un-checked one; or make use of CSS selectors (using `querySelectorAll`) to begin with, and compare the number of “all checkboxes” against “checked checkboxes”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add the same listener to both checkboxes, and have that listener check the state of both. Then, if both are not checked, display the `fill`:

```js
const isCheckeds = document.querySelectorAll('.is-checked');
const fill = document.querySelector('#fill');
function validate() {
  let anyChecked = false;
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((checkbox, i) => {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      anyChecked = true;
    }
    isCheckeds[i].style.display = checkbox.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
  fill.style.display = anyChecked ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

```html
<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()"><br>
Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" onclick="validate()">

<p id="fill">No boxes are checked</p>

<p class="is-checked" style="display:none">Checkbox1 is CHECKED!</p>
<p class="is-checked" style="display:none">Checkbox2 is CHECKED!</p>
```

Note that inline handlers [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045). Strongly consider attaching them properly with Javascript instead. You could also consider using a `change` listener instead of a `click` listener (for better accessablity), and you could surround the inputs in a `<label>` to make them more clickable:

```js
const isCheckeds = document.querySelectorAll('.is-checked');
const fill = document.querySelector('#fill');
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input');
function validate() {
  let anyChecked = false;
  checkboxes.forEach((checkbox, i) => {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      anyChecked = true;
    }
    isCheckeds[i].style.display = checkbox.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
  fill.style.display = anyChecked ? 'none' : 'block';
}
for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', validate);
}
```

```html
<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

<label>Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox"></label><br>
<label>Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox"></label>

<p id="fill">No boxes are checked</p>

<p class="is-checked" style="display:none">Checkbox1 is CHECKED!</p>
<p class="is-checked" style="display:none">Checkbox2 is CHECKED!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define fill through a document.getElementById in the second checkbox. Right now you are disabling the fill on the first checkbox when interacting with the second one. I think this is causing some problems.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited it and it's still the same.

Comment: @f-boersma Please, try to add a comment and clarify the problem before giving the strict answer, that could not solve the issue

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. Will remember that for future questions!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not necessary for this task: with your markup structure you could use `CSS` only

```css
:checked ~ p, #cb1, #cb2 {
  display: none;
}


#check1:checked ~ #cb1,
#check2:checked ~ #cb2 { display: block; }
```

```html
<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" id="check1"><br>
Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" id="check2">

<p id="cb0">No boxes are checked</p>
<p id="cb1">Checkbox1 is checked</p>
<p id="cb2">Checkbox2 is checked!</p>
```